# wamp sever could not display the success or errormessage with my php script

Tags: php, localhost, database-connection, wampserver

I write a PHP script to display the message like
if the connection is success it display the message **Welcome to WampServer**,   else it gives an error message like **Connection error.....**
but here when i try to connect the Wampserver, it displayed my Code, as the result.What is the problem here, will you please solve this problem and also please explain me elaborately.

```php
<?php
$db_name="webappdb";
$mysql_user="root";
$mysql_pass="root";
$server_name="localhost";
$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);
if(!$con){
echo "Connection error...".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else{
echo"<h3>Database Connection Success....</h3>"
}


?>
```

Below is my Code what i used.This code i saved in the folder     **C:\wamp64\www\webapps**
for connected to the data base i used this in the web **localhost/webappdb/webapps**

Comment: this is PHP script file, that's why i am extended it as .php

Comment: i am saving the file like this  **init.php** @SaileshChowdaryDoppalapudi

Comment: Thanks, for your Answer Sailesh, just i am doing the mistake of saving file. Am saving the file wigh .txt extention this am changing into .php extention. Then i solve my problem

Comment: Dont use `notepad` as a script editor!!!! Try `notepad++` its free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using edit plus then there is no need to extend your php file with .php extension. suppose your are using a note pad to write php script to connect Wampserver or to got a connection success report from server it is necessary to extend the file with .php other wise it gives or behave abnormally.Gives result like what your are mentioned above.
First my suggestion is if your are using a note pad to write a any coding extend that file with that jar file like php with .php and java .java like

Comment: Yes here i am facing exactly same problem

Comment: yes i am facing exactly that problem when i am starting a work that's why i mentioned it clearly@ballu

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @JDBC

Comment: i have one doubt.If i am using edit pluse there is no need to exend it with .php

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this Problem is,
When i am creating a php file, i am doing the mistake of saving the file with .php extension. instead of .php extension am saving the file with .txt extension this is the mistake what am doing.

If any body got same problem what am facing Please check once your saving file extension. it is in .php extension or not.
to got .php extension save your file in double cotes with .php. 
for example you file name is **init** you save file like **"init.php"**

Answer (score -1):

enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your php script file, then you will get errors

Comment: can you please tell me, how can i enable that (i am not very much familiar with php) @jack brone

Comment: just add this line in your php script file at the top position, error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: If the script is not executing, this is not going to be any help